# How to update charts using models?

Tags: qt, widget, qml, qtableview, qtcharts

I am using [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-modeldata-customtablemodel-cpp.html) example instead of customtablemodel.cpp I changed its name to ScopeDataModel and I am using it in my qml code. But when I run this code it is not updating the data on the chart.

```
 ScopeDataModel{ 
    id:scopeModel
}
ChartView
{
    id: chartView
    title: " Scope "
    anchors.fill: parent
    legend.visible: false
    antialiasing: true
    backgroundColor: "white"
    plotAreaColor: "white"
    titleColor: "white"

    ValueAxis {
        id: axisX
        titleText:componentData.readXAxisName
        min: componentData.changeXMin
        max: componentData.changeXMax
        tickCount: 1
    }

    ValueAxis {
        id: axisY
        titleText:componentData.readYAxisName
        min: componentData.changeYMin
        max: componentData.changeYMax
        tickCount: 1
    }

    LineSeries {

        id: lineSeries
        name: "Data Output"
        axisX: axisX
        axisY: axisY
        useOpenGL: true
        VXYModelMapper{
        model:scopeModel
        xColumn:0
        yColumn:1
        series:lineSeries
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By the code you've provided you don't set data to the model and make no changes to it.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. Can you please help me out on how I can set the data for the same ?

Comment: If you have your model defined in Qt, you can use:QQmlContext *context = view.engine()->rootContext();
    context->setContextProperty("_myModel", &model);